# how to remove last value localstorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I want to ask you something guys, I hope you can help. I am confused how to remove last value from localstorage? the localstorage value I have as below, I want to delete the 'Sprints' value. If i use `localStorage.removeItem('tags')`, all values ​​will be deleted right? but I just want remove the last value. please help me, cause i'm confused

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`localStorage` is only capable of storing string values so what you've got there is an array, serialised to JSON.

To remove elements from it, you'll need to

1. Parse the string as JSON to an array
2. Remove the item
3. Stringify the array and put it back in `localStorage`

```js
const tags = JSON.parse(localStorage.tags ?? "[]")
localStorage.tags = JSON.stringify(tags.slice(0, -1))
```

You can of course *single-line* this

```js
localStorage.tags = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(localStorage.tags ?? "[]").slice(0, -1))
```

Comment: Also seems to work but less readable lol `localStorage.tags = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tags')).pop())`

Comment: @Jacob that won't work since `pop()` returns the removed element. You'd need to use `.slice(0, -1)`

Comment: aww crap, you're absolutely right. Also why I shouldn't code around midnight. Thanks for catching that asinine blunder @Phil